# The report server was unable to validate the integrity of encrypted data

Tags: sql-server, encryption, reporting-services, sql-server-2016

The report server was unable to validate the integrity of encrypted data in the database. (rsCannotValidateEncryptedData) .

Could not restore the encryption key, so I deleted the keys and tried to regenerate with rskeymngt with no luck. Getting

> 'The report server was unable to validate the integrity of encrypted
>   data in the database. (rsCannotValidateEncryptedData)'

I get that error when accessing `http://localhost/ReportServer` and when running `rskeymgmt -s`.

Not sure what next step to take. I have reports that users need to access.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you suing?

Comment: Sql server 2016

Comment: Inside rs configuration manager I changed the Report Server Service account and it asked to generate key. I am now getting HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

Comment: I restarted the services and no longer getting the 503 error. I can see the reports but it is asking for data source creds. I enter them and get The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.

Answer (score 33):

I went into SSRS Configuration Manager > Encryption Keys > click Delete.

When I did that I got the error:

> Failed to delete the encryption content in the report server database. Please execute the "DeleteEncryptedContent" stored procedure on the database manually.

To fix it I opened SQL Server Mgmt Studio > expand Databases > right click Report Server > new query and execute:

```
exec DeleteEncryptedContent
```

Start > Run > *services.msc* > Restart the "SQL Server Reporting Service" and its working.

Comment: which service? sql server reporting service?

Comment: Well that was worthless...

Comment: @Logany-hi why? Not every solution fixes every problem. This worked for me and 29 other people.

Answer (score 4):

Restarted the services and now everything is working.

So it looks like in order to generate a new key I need to update the Report Server Service account. After that restart the sql server reporting services.

I no longer have the encryption error, but now I am asked for a log in to the data source after clicking on the report. I enter the creds again but get 'The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.'

Answer (score 3):

Just go to the reporting service manager and delete the delete encrypted content or change content now try to connect once more it will be work.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change database again if you already created then your problem will be solved.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One reason for this could be that the encryption key did not restore correctly. I migrated a report database from one server to another. I restored the encryption key and all seemed well at first but the error the questioner posted started appearing shortly thereafter. Another site had posted a query to look at the keys in the report database (with further instructions of how to delete) and I noticed when I executed it that the `SymmetricKey` field for my server was `NULL`. I restored the encryption key again using the Report Server Configuration Manager and noticed that the `SymmetricKeys` was now populated. I was then able to browse to the report server.

Comment: So... don't post the query to look at the keys or a link to the site where you found it... or anything useful at all for that matter. Why did you bother writing an answer in the first place?

Comment: select * from reportserver.dbo.keys